# Azure-pipelines when triggered on a bitbucket pr doesn't appear to run on a merged git ref

Tags: git, bitbucket, azure-pipelines, pull-request

I have a azure pipelines run that looks like the following:

```
trigger:
- master

pr:
- azure-pipelines-test

steps:
- script: echo "Build Sourcebranch $BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH"
  displayName: Sourcebranch echo.

- script: tree
  displayName: tree
```

When I add to a branch that has an open pull request to `azure-pipelines-test` from `azure-pipelines-pr-test`, I am getting the `SourceBranch` = `refs/heads/azure-pipelines-pr-test`, which is just the head of the source branch.

I have also made modifications to `azure-pipelines-test` (added an empty file) that are not in `azure-pipelines-pr-test`.  These modifications don't show up when I do a `tree` in the pipeline.

In the azure-pipelines documentation for a pull request, it says that there is a merge commit between the two branches in the pull request that is used to run the pipeline on... but that doesn't appear to be what is happening.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong?

You're not doing wrong, instead I think there's something wrong with the `trigger+checkout` process.

I've reproduced same issue on my side and reported this issue [in our user voice forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1132663/yaml-pr-trigger-for-bitbucket-repo-doesnt-work-as.html). You can track it to get notifications if there's any update from product team.